# Print lesser string from multiple command-line arguments

Tags: java, string, arguments

I want to extend my current program to accept any number of command line arguments and prints the lesser of them (case sensitive). Currently it's like so:

```
public class StringCompare {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s1 = new String(args[0]);
        String s2 = new String(args[1]);

        if (s1.compareTo(s2) > 0) {
            System.out.println(s2);
        }
        else if (s1.compareTo(s2) < 0) {
            System.out.println(s1);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Both are equal.");
        }       
    }
}
```

Example of what I'm after:

```
Input: aaa aa a aAa

Output: a
```

What would be an elegant way to approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Java 8 syntax and lambdas you can do it as following:

**EDITED(Based on suggestion in comment by @ Aominè)**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String min = Arrays.stream(args)
             .min(String::compareTo)
           .orElse("<none>");

    System.out.println(min);
}
```

---

If you'd like to know if all string are equal you might want to add an additional step to check for it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String min = Arrays.stream(args)
            .min(String::compareTo)
        .orElse("<none>");

    if (!Arrays.stream(args)
            .allMatch(x-> x.equals(min))) {
        System.out.println(min);
    } else {
        System.out.println("All are equal.");
    }
}
```

Comment: `Arrays.asList(args).stream()` is uncessary and causes overhead when `args` contains alot of elements. So, I'd use `Arrays.stream(args).min(String::compareTo);` instead. Also, you're not using `Optional` correctly. I'd suggest using `IfPresent` before the `get` call or instead something like `string smallestElement = Arrays.stream(args).min(String::compareTo).orElse(enterSomeDefaultValueOrNull);`

Answer (score 1):

using a for loop, and a temp (lesser) String variable.

```
//validate args , not null, and length != 0

if(args == null || args.length ==0){
    System.out.println("No strings to compare");
    return;
}
string lesser = args[0]; // assume 1st argument is the lesser.
for(int a=0;a<args.length;a++){
    if (lesser.compareTo(args[a]) > 0) {
        lesser = args[a];// the new lesser string
    }
    //we ignore other cases (args[a] is larger or equals, cuz we want lesser only
}

System.out.println("Lesser String is " + lesser);
```